# Submit form twice to different destinations

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, submit

I am trying to submit a form to a page within my domain, then resubmit it automatically to another domain.

The code below works fine up to the point of resubmitting. It changes the action on the form OK and removes the ID so it should submit like a normal form the second time around.

Can anyone see the problem as to why it won't resubmit?

Thanks

```
$("form#dataForm").validate({
    // Validation code here...
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post('queries/pay.php', $("#dataForm").serialize(), function(data) {
            $("#dataForm").removeAttr("id").attr({
                "action":data.action
            }, function() {
                $("form").submit(); // This part of the code does not work
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess, depending on which browser you'll use, this may be blocked by built-in XSS filters, when submitting a form to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("form").unbind('submit').submit();
```